# Instrumentation Amplifier Input Impedance

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am having trouble calculating the Instrumentation amplifier Input Impedance, I know that it has a high input impedance because two non-inverting op amps are connected, but I don't know where to start from.

Comment: Show schematics and an indication of the devices used.  If you can't post the details (because of limited rep count) post them here in comments and others will clean it up for you.

Comment: You don't calculate it. It is dependent on the input impedance of the op amps themselves.

Answer (score 1):

An INA uses two opamps as input buffer. Input impedance is determined by the opamp. Read datasheet for input impedance if you are using single IC opamp. Or simulate with the specific signal frequency on SPICE if you are building one from transistors. Basically it depends on the gate of input MOSFET or base of BJT.

Answer (score 0):

The input impedances at the INA inputs depend on the particular operational conditions. This is because the input opamps have negative feedback which drastically increases the input impedances at the non-inv. inputs.

However, the corresponding loop gain (which gives the enlargement factor) depends (1) on the selected gain (common resistor RG) as well as the signal voltage at the other input. Hence, the input impedances are very large, but are dependend on operational conditions.

Remark: Keep in mind that the above explanation is based on (theoretical) formulas/relations only. Because the input impedance will be rather large you must take into account in addition parasitic capacitances at the various nodes.